# ExtJS Session Viewing Details

Tags: extjs

To make my app load, I am making an "Ext.Ajax.request" and if it succeeds, I load it, if it fails, then I display error and redirect the user. So, given it successfully loads, I want to create a session (which I did, by writing as first element within success condition "session: true;"..

My main question is, how can I print on the screen or view in inspect of Google Chrome, the session element? Like when session gets created, there should be multiple elements created like Session ID and etc, how do I view those?

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '',
        method: '',
        useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
        withCredentials: true,
        jsonData: {
            activationCode: ""
        },
        scope: this,
        success: function (response) {
            "success ... code that does stuff"
            session: true;
            successLoginFunction();
        },
        failure: function(response) {
                "failed ... code that does stuff"
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Add some code to your question. We need to see what you have done so far in order to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.util.Cookies.set("JSON", xxx);
```